# Anyone know whether there is a 5-star rating control for asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I require a  star rating control (which allows partial rating like 4.5)  for my application built on asp.net mvc.

Any pointers in this direction will be helpful?

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question at hand, but depending on your application, you might consider a thumbs up/down type rating system rather than a 5-star (especially if going for public ratings). Google seems to agree, as they've changed their rating from stars to thumbs. See http://www.techcrunch.com/2009/09/22/youtube-comes-to-a-5-star-realization-its-ratings-are-useless/ . Although, it seems to work for Netflix, so that's why it's application specific.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rogie, over at [Komodomedia](http://www.komodomedia.com/blog/), has spent far too long on this [topic](http://www.komodomedia.com/blog/2005/08/creating-a-star-rater-using-css/) [writing](http://www.komodomedia.com/blog/2005/08/creating-a-star-rater-using-css/) 3 [articles](http://www.komodomedia.com/blog/2007/01/css-star-rating-redux/) on the topic.

[Just in case anyone got lost in the link-soup this is the latest.](http://www.komodomedia.com/blog/2007/01/css-star-rating-redux/)

It's not MVC specific, but it is cross browser and allows you to get the value back via postback or ajax.

Answer (score 4):

Meanwhile I found this link with example in asp.net.
http://beckelman.net/post/2008/08/30/Survey-Using-jQuery-Star-Rating-Widget.aspx

This is pretty helpful.

Thanks everyone for the help.

Answer (score 3):

I know its not a control, but I found it very easy to implement.

I just implemented this on one of my sites using MVC and it worked beautifully.

http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/114/jQuery-Star-Rating-with-ASP.NET-MVC

Answer (score 2):

This one is my favorite Rating plug-in for JQuery:

http://rateit.codeplex.com/

it comes with good examples: 
http://www.radioactivethinking.com/rateit/example/example.htm

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple in the jQuery plug-in list that will be able to do what you require.  However there is no specific control for MVC yet.

Answer (score 1):

I tried looking at the links given as response however was not that happy and I developed my own star rating system here and have wrote an article of how I have done it. Hope this will be helpful

http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/2828/developing-a-star-rating-in-aspnet-mvc

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but I like to answer it for everybody who will find this post through search engines.

This article explains how to implement a star rating system for MVC.
I have implemented it and it works like a charm.

http://www.codecapers.com/post/Building-a-Star-Rating-System-with-ASPNET-MVC-and-jQuery.aspx